# Strange ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for Java SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat, indexoutofboundsexception

We run Java 1.4.

We have this method:

```
static SimpleDateFormat xmlFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

public static Date fromXml(String xmlDateTime) {
    ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
    return xmlFormatter.parse(xmlDateTime, pp);
}
```

Where `xmlDateTime = 2013-08-22T16:03:00` for example. This has been working, but suddenly stopped!

We now get this exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.text.DigitList.fitsIntoLong(DigitList.java:170)
at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:1064)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1381)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1159)
```

I have tried to reproduce this in a Unit Test by using different date formats, ie:

```
2013-08-22T16:03:00
2013-08-22 16:03:00
```

But no luck! Any ideas?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It is a little known fact that `SimpleDateFormat` is **not threadsafe**!

It is *not* a bug: The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documents this behaviour:

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

Create an instance every time you need one, or if performance is a real issue, you could try using [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to store an instance for each thread that needs one.

---

Don't feel bad: I fell for exactly this "optimization" (to reuse a single constant instance), and to my amazement, had to instantiate a new instance every time.

Comment: When `joda-time` library is present then `DateTimeFormat`can be used. It's immutable and therefore threadsafe like everything in joda-time. btw +1

Comment: I had the same issue on Android, but with formatting a date. How could it be that it's not thread safe? Seems to me that it should have a very generic algorithm inside, which doesn't need to assume anything about threads...

Comment: @android it's not threadsafe because the moron(s) who coded it decided to not make it threadsafe. Java 8's `DateTimeFormatter` et al *is* threadsafe however.

Comment: @Bohemian Sadly Java 8 is in very early stage on Android. I will just create a new instance per thread, using clone.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4699765). The underlying reason was diagnosed to be that `DecimalFormat` simply isn't thread safe.

So you should not use the same `SimpleDateFormat` instance on different threads, since it, and `DecimalFormat` still aren't thread safe.

You could use `ThreadLocal` to have each thread use its own instance.

Comment: Looks like that bug only affected Java 3.

Comment: The link is a bit misleading, because people reading your answer think that you're stating that this is a bug. And it is not a bug. I recommend deleting the sentence with the link.

Comment: The resolution was to make DecimalFormat thread safe, it still isn't in Java 7, so I guess the behavior can occur even on a modern JDK.

Comment: @FabianBarney clarified the usefulness of the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Commons Lang 3.x FastDateParser and FastDateFormat. These classes are thread safe and faster than SimpleDateFormat. They also support the same format/parse pattern specifications as SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: This helped me a lot today.. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to create instance each time, a local/scope variable instead of global variable, it works for me

```
private void test {
    SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
    // Do somethings
}
```