# Strange java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException rendering error in jsf application under high load

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

We have a fairly complex jsf view.

We are creating view using c:forEach on multiple tabs.

On high load we get a rendering error and this error strangely spreads to other users views. The error that we got under high load is :

```
17:43:43,951 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (HTTP-689) Error Rendering View[/default.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /default.xhtml: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:88) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:207) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:104) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:560) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1042) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1819) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:104) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:560) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1042) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1819) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:104) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:560) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1042) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:79) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:307) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:265) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:131) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:71) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:79) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1819) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:447) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:511) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:808)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:828)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

After we got this error on every user that comes after this error occurs got the same error.

We are using Mojarra on Jboss eap with primefaces.

The jsf code is in my native language. I can post it if you want.

Has anyone come across this kind of behaviour?

Comment: As usual in exceptions, the bottommost "Caused by" contains detail about the root cause of all the trouble. Yet this information is missing in the question. All exceptions thereafter (the top ones in stack trace) are just wrapped/rethrown consequences. My educated guess based on information provided so far is that it's related to incorrectly binding UI components to a bean property of a non-request scoped managed bean. In other words, you made the UI component instances non-threadsafe.

Comment: Thanks I will look at the problematic case with a race condition in my mind. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're indeed using `binding` on a non-request scoped managed bean property, carefully read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14911158

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383251/strange-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-for-java-simpledateformat This may cause the error in our rendering. We had shared a static SimpleDateFormat among threads. The strange thing it does not seem on the stack trace on later requests. But on the first request that the incident happens we see the correct line of code. Does it make sense to your super experience @BlausC ? Forgive my language but I am thankful to you

Comment: That depends on bottommost "Cause by" part which is missing in the question. But indeed, `DateFormat` instances are not thread safe.